# Nested Divs\Grids 960 not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, nested

I am using the 960 grid system to layout a webpage for an employer. I am attempting to create a div that spans 6 columns, with three nested divs that span 2 columns each. When I attempt to do this the last nested div is pushed out of the parent div. I have tested this on IE 11, Chrome 37 and Firefox 32 and all browsers display the last nested div outside the parent div. I am using the alpha and omega tags, it appears the omega tag is not working on the last nested div. The omega tag should reduce the right margin to 0 on the tagged div and allow all three nested divs to fit inside the parent div.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>gridtest</title>
<link href="12col.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container_12">

    <div class="grid_6 push_3 Box">
      <div class="grid_2 alpha">
      </div>
      <div class="grid_2  ">
      </div>
      <div class="grid_2 omega">
      </div>    
   </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
            /*
              960 Grid System ~ Core CSS.
              Learn more ~ http://960.gs/

              Licensed under GPL and MIT.
            */

            /*
              Forces backgrounds to span full width,
              even if there is horizontal scrolling.
              Increase this if your layout is wider.

              Note: IE6 works fine without this fix.
            */

            body {
              min-width: 960px;

            }

            /* `Container
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .container_12 {
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
              width: 960px;
              border: black 3px solid;
              height:960px;
            }

            /* `Grid >> Global
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .grid_1,
            .grid_2,
            .grid_3,
            .grid_4,
            .grid_5,
            .grid_6,
            .grid_7,
            .grid_8,
            .grid_9,
            .grid_10,
            .grid_11,
            .grid_12 {
              display: inline;
              float: left;
              margin-left: 10px;
              margin-right: 10px;
            }

            .push_1, .pull_1,
            .push_2, .pull_2,
            .push_3, .pull_3,
            .push_4, .pull_4,
            .push_5, .pull_5,
            .push_6, .pull_6,
            .push_7, .pull_7,
            .push_8, .pull_8,
            .push_9, .pull_9,
            .push_10, .pull_10,
            .push_11, .pull_11 {
              position: relative;
            }

            /* `Grid >> Children (Alpha ~ First, Omega ~ Last)
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .alpha {
              margin-left: 0;
            }

            .omega {
              margin-right: 0;
            }

            /* `Grid >> 12 Columns
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .container_12 .grid_1 {
              width: 60px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_2 {
              width: 140px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_3 {
              width: 220px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_4 {
              width: 300px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_5 {
              width: 380px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_6 {
              width: 460px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_7 {
              width: 540px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_8 {
              width: 620px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_9 {
              width: 700px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_10 {
              width: 780px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_11 {
              width: 860px;
            }

            .container_12 .grid_12 {
              width: 940px;
            }

            /* `Prefix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .container_12 .prefix_1 {
              padding-left: 80px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_2 {
              padding-left: 160px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_3 {
              padding-left: 240px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_4 {
              padding-left: 320px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_5 {
              padding-left: 400px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_6 {
              padding-left: 480px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_7 {
              padding-left: 560px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_8 {
              padding-left: 640px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_9 {
              padding-left: 720px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_10 {
              padding-left: 800px;
            }

            .container_12 .prefix_11 {
              padding-left: 880px;
            }

            /* `Suffix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .container_12 .suffix_1 {
              padding-right: 80px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_2 {
              padding-right: 160px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_3 {
              padding-right: 240px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_4 {
              padding-right: 320px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_5 {
              padding-right: 400px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_6 {
              padding-right: 480px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_7 {
              padding-right: 560px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_8 {
              padding-right: 640px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_9 {
              padding-right: 720px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_10 {
              padding-right: 800px;
            }

            .container_12 .suffix_11 {
              padding-right: 880px;
            }

            /* `Push Space >> 12 Columns
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .container_12 .push_1 {
              left: 80px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_2 {
              left: 160px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_3 {
              left: 240px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_4 {
              left: 320px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_5 {
              left: 400px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_6 {
              left: 480px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_7 {
              left: 560px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_8 {
              left: 640px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_9 {
              left: 720px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_10 {
              left: 800px;
            }

            .container_12 .push_11 {
              left: 880px;
            }

            /* `Pull Space >> 12 Columns
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            .container_12 .pull_1 {
              left: -80px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_2 {
              left: -160px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_3 {
              left: -240px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_4 {
              left: -320px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_5 {
              left: -400px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_6 {
              left: -480px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_7 {
              left: -560px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_8 {
              left: -640px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_9 {
              left: -720px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_10 {
              left: -800px;
            }

            .container_12 .pull_11 {
              left: -880px;
            }

            /* `Clear Floated Elements
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            /* http://sonspring.com/journal/clearing-floats */

            .clear {
              clear: both;
              display: block;
              overflow: hidden;
              visibility: hidden;
              width: 0;
              height: 0;
            }

            /* http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified */

            .clearfix:before,
            .clearfix:after,
            .container_12:before,
            .container_12:after {
              content: '.';
              display: block;
              overflow: hidden;
              visibility: hidden;
              font-size: 0;
              line-height: 0;
              width: 0;
              height: 0;
            }

            .clearfix:after,
            .container_12:after {
              clear: both;
            }

            /*
              The following zoom:1 rule is specifically for IE6 + IE7.
              Move to separate stylesheet if invalid CSS is a problem.
            */

            .clearfix,
            .container_12 {
              zoom: 1;
            }

            .Box {
                height:175px;
                border: red 2px dashed;


            }

            .Box div {

                height:170px;
                border:blue 1px solid;

             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you give the box div a border of 1 px, this makes the boxes too big, so the last one gets into a new row.

Remove: `border:blue 1px solid;` from `.Box div` and everything should work fine.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d9qjb1dn/)**

**OR**

Add: 'box-sizing:border-box;' to '.Box div'

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d9qjb1dn/1/)**

[Read more about box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i feel a little dumb right now.